# Can I use the Facebook SDK to login automatically (using cron) and save the access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

I want to store the full access token in my site. Is it possible to use the Facebook API and login with crontab every hour? If I can, can you point me to the documentation that talks about this?

```
require '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '13XXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'fbXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
  $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
echo $access_token;
```

**UPDATE**:

My purpose is to provide a search box for the public so that everyone can search facebook without requiring a login.

I have tried

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&access_token=1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx‌​|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,read_stream
```

But it returns an error `"message": "A user access token is required to request this resource."`

And I see someone has developed a site that does facebook search at http://www.fbsearch.us/q/mark/5

How does that work?

Comment: i'm not sure what you're trying to do but if you need to access a profile without logging in why not just use the offline_access permission?

Comment: @Jeffery A Wooden, I want make many stuff, some api call needs full access token, such as `peaple search`, it is not convenient for user if they do not have fb account / if they do not like to do a accept of the app pop box. thanks.

Comment: @fishman this sounds like what you're trying to do is probably a [policy violation](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). If you are using one user access token to expose information to another user, that's not kosher because you're not respecting privacy settings or blocked users. If user A blocked user B and you use user C's access token to show user B content about user A, that's really bad.

Comment: @Jeff Bowen, thanks. so is it possible `search people` without `full access token`? I see some guy can do that see
http://www.fbsearch.us/q/mark/5

Comment: Just because he can do it doesn't make it ok.  This is a clear violation of Facebook's platform policy.  If they find out they will take action against you.

Comment: @fishman, no. You need to use a user access token to search for people via the API so you'd need to have the user authenticate. The link you referenced is either done via violating policy or more likely by crawling FB public profiles like Google or other search engines do.

Comment: +1 for Jeff. I don't like it! stackoverflow should not help people violating privacy concerns and other policies.

Comment: @Stefan,  I am honest, never changed my question title, I asked few days ago, because I see `fbsearch.us` has an example. Now look at my `update2`, this edit by 7 hours ago, earlier than your comment. I will obey the privacy, let user first login, then for a search. Now can u answer my `update2` question? I think `no`, because u also can not help people who even obey the privacy. No matter `-1`, thank u.

Comment: @Stefan I agree with all above that This is a clear violation of Facebook's platform policy and if you want to ask another question please click [Ask Question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) its not good to change your question and if you found this is violating facebook polices so its better to close or delete this question..
Thanks...

Comment: So which question answer will get the bounty?  The first or the second or the third?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to your third revision...

I've accomplished saving the user state by

a) saving the last url into the user session context

b) directing the login success form to a server script that will save the credentials into the same session context and then redirects the browser to the last url or default welcome page.

The redirect url is attached to the oauth login dialog:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

After the user authorizes your app, FB redirects the user back to the redirect_uri with the access token in the URI fragment:

```
https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page?access_token=...
```

excerpts from [facebook-getLoginUrl](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) and [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

You may have to append YOUR_URL with the session id if it doesn't translate directly (likely because of crossing http/https/http).

This way the user sees the least transition from the facebook login form an authenticated app page and can ignore the actual credentials.

Be careful, methods like this may be compromised by XSS and other [OWASP Top 10 Vulnerabilities](http://xml.coverpages.org/OWASP-TopTen.pdf)

Comment: do u have an example for reference? Still not find a work code as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(sizeof($_GET['q']) > 0)
{ 
    $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
    require_once('facebook_app/facebook.php'); 
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $app_id ,
      'secret' => $app_secret,
    ));
    $fb_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='{$_GET['q']}'&type=user&access_token=$fb_access_token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 80000);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($curl_errno > 0) {
            echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
    } else {
    $decoded = json_decode($data);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($decoded->data);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
}
else
{
?>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var sQuery = $('#sQuery').val();
        $.get("fbsearch.php", {q: sQuery}, function(results) 
        {
            console.log(results);
            $('div#results').fadeIn(function() {
                $('div#results').html(results);
            });
        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
      oauth      : true
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
<input type="text" id="sQuery">
<button id="submit">Search</button>
<div id="results" style="display:none;"></div>
<?php
}?>
```

Comment: -1, you never read completed question in `UPDATE2` and my anwser `14 hours ago`. Notice: some one edited my question yesterday.

Comment: Try this link to see the revisions: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/posts/9174107/revisions

Comment: @Damien Keitel, I need a search `type=user`.  No matter, this is a bad question. over it, `+1`, thanks for your participate.

Answer (score 0):

It not possible simulate facebook account to login with crontab. Skipping the confirm step is not possible because skipping any step will not generate the access_token. The only way out is to use offline_access permission and generate an access_token. All requests performed to facebook can be done with this access_token.

The possible way out is; you provide an offine_access permission to your application and store the user access_token somewhere in the application. Maybe hard code it. Make sure you do not disclose it publicly. This access_token is hard coded somewhere on your server side files and not HTML or js files.

Submit a form with all the required parameters; eg: q=mark and type=user. From your server fire a curl request to graph.facebook.com with the parameters and access_token. You will get a JSON response that you can return back to you HTML view. You can also use ajax to make it seamless. In either of the cases; HTTP request or XHR request the access_token is never disclosed to the user.

You can make the application is bit smart by using the access_token of users who have logged into their facebook account and your access_token for users who do not have facebook accounts.

Comment: I have tried a short access_token like `1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` I can use it search all the type, but people. `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&access_token=1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,read_stream`. it show error `"message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",` so do you have any idea to get it? thanks.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark searches all the status updates that public. https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user does need the user access_token to query. the scope parameter added really does not make sense as you are not requesting for any permissions

Answer (score 0):

> A user access token is required to request this resource

Currently you're sending application access token (`APP_ID|SECRET_TOKEN`) which is not enough. To make sure you can search, you have to get **user** access token (for example yours) and search through that one.

So what you need is:

- Go to this URL

  https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,read_stream&client_id=**YOUR_APP_ID**&redirect_uri=**YOUR_URL**
- Approve all permissions
- Facebook will redirect you back to your website with `code` parameter
- Send that code to

  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=**YOUR_APP_ID**&client_secret=**APP_SECRET**&code=**CODE_YOU_GOT**

here you got an access token. This access token will be used for all actions like crontab execution.

### Be warned

Only do this if you're sure you're not violating Facebook's privacy policy! It is fine to post on your wall with this method from crontab for example, but it's not ok to let people search others as they may be blocked!

Comment: i request you please read above comments and check his question again This is a clear violation of Facebook's platform policy
Thanks...

Comment: @DanishIqbal: I read them. Did you read that **bold big block "Be warned"** ? I assume someone may want to know how to exactly use offline_access, and offline_access isn't just for bad purposes.

Comment: please dont mind my comment but i think its better to don't show the code to those persons who want to misuse 
and you are right about my answer :)
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am not sure why many people never read full question about me, and why my question was edited by other user?

Firstly, I ask this question, because I see `fbsearch.us`, then after `Atul Agrawal`, `Lix` and more user remind me this is violation of Facebook's platform policy. **I am sorry, this is my fault**

So I update my question, **I will obey the policy.** And update my question, **but I do not want a long url like** `state=85202ba5222f95ba7fee0c78ff1971dc&code=AQBGsJjT92gALrAjTCI0XQIXht......`,

I never find a way under `PHP SDK`, but some way in `JS SDK`

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '140174749371026',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });
        function FBLogin() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {                            
                    ConnectFacebookUser(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                } else {
                }
            }, { scope: 'email' });
        }
        $('#fb-button').live('click', function (e) {
            FBLogin();

            e.preventDefault();
        });
        function ConnectFacebookUser(accesstoken) {
            alert(accesstoken)
        }
    };
</script>


<a href="#" id="fb-button">Login with facebook</a>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Anyone have method under `PHP SDK`? I hope now people cauld stop talking about `policy`, and discuss `web technology`. Thanks.

Comment: do you read my comment in your question?
i request you please if you find that your question violates fb policy so its better to close this question and if you want to ask a new question than ask a new question not edit on the previous question and not ask the question in answer
Thanks..

Comment: @Danish Iqbal, sorry, +1 to make balance. I have lost more points in this question. I also know open a new question is more better. but I have no time to wait a new question and a new bounty. over this unhappy question. thanks for your help.

Comment: i understand your point and i appreciate your point and decision that you accept the answer